# I am using handler for delay in android but it's not working

Tags: java, android, android-things

I want a delay for two seconds. and every 2 seconds I want to change the text, and for that, I am using handler like this, but it's not working it's only showing hello. it's not changing at all it only shows what I write second. The code is like this,

```
      private Handler handler = new Handler();

      int i=5;

      private TextView textView ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setText("Android Things !!");
    hello_first.run();


}

private Runnable hello_first = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

            textView.setText("Nice Work");
            handler.postDelayed(this,5000);
            textView.setText("Hello");
            handler.postDelayed(this,2000);

            i = i+1;
            if(i==5)
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: you call `textView.setText("Nice Work");` and couple of nanoseconds later `textView.setText("Hello");` - as a result only `"Hello"` is shown

Comment: well, that's the problem, it's not waiting for a couple of nanoseconds directly gives me hello.

Comment: well, `handler.postDelayed(this,5000);` takes some CPU cycles - thats why i said about `"couple of nanoseconds"`

Comment: I want a delay when text chang

Comment: @ParthKabariya, do  you want a change text at every 2 seconds interval or just 1 or 2 time?

Comment: I am working on Android things. So, I need both sometimes 2 or 3 times or sometimes continue.

Comment: I am new to android so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: thank again. I solved it by using List<String> and I am using get() method with index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `postDelayed` incorrectly. It looks like you expect it to work the same way `Thread.sleep` would work. However that is not the case.

Here is a correct implementation of what you are trying to achieve:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TextView textView;

private int i = 0;
private boolean flip;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    handler.post(hello_first);
}

private Runnable hello_first = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            if(++i == 5) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                return;
            }

            if(flip) {
                textView.setText("Nice Work");  
            } else {
                textView.setText("Hello");
            }
            flip = !flip;

            handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));           
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to use like

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            textView.setText("Hello");

        },2000);


handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
textView.setText("Nice Work");},5000);
```

Comment: thanks for an answer. But it's not working only print hello. have you tried it?

Comment: I have edited u can use 2 handler for setting 2 text as above @ParthKabariya

Comment: that's I know I don't want to use two handlers that's why I posted it but again thanks, if i don't get any solution i will use this :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setText("Android Things !!");
    handler.postDelayed(hello_first,5000);
    handler.postDelayed(hello_second,2000);
}

private Runnable hello_first = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Nice Work");
    }
};
private Runnable hello_second = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Hello");
    }
};
```

Comment: well, it only shows hello because when hello_frist call it set a text to textview to hello. thanks for ans.

Comment: you need to use two runnables. check the updated answer @ParthKabariya

Comment: thanks, I appreciate this, I don't wanna use two handlers that's why I posted this question. and I got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this will work for you.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
  Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Nice Work");
        handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
        textView.setText("Hello");
        handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
    }
};
task.run();
```

For Stopping task

```
handler.removeCallbacks(task);
```

Comment: see in the code I have done the same thing, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> A [**`Handler`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue.

Rectify your [**`postDelayed`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postdelayed) method.

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses.

**DEMO STRUCTURE**

```
textView.setText("Nice Work");
final Handler handlerOBJ = new Handler();
    handlerOBJ.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // YOUR WORK
       textView.setText("Hello");
      }
    }, 5000); // 5S delay
```

Comment: my work is just changing text every two seconds and if I do the way you told me I always get hello, I have given the code and I have done the same thing that you told me.

Comment: @ParthKabariya You should increase time.

Comment: that's why I have given 5000 for first text. it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can Log and see what happened actually...

Every time you call `handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);`
it will create two Runnable instance and send them to the handler. So the number of runnable in the queue increase very quickly.

You can set a text list and index, and then throw the runnable to the handler and postDealyed as 2000 milliseconds. Use the text list and index to see what text should be set to the textview.